# How to fetch data from Archive database

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

i'm working with Dynamics ax 2012 and I've archived data with IDMF

Is there any way to show both of live data and archived data in Ax Grids ,

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary table and combine the live data and archived data at runtime in this table. You can then use the temporary table in a form grid.

But I would question why this data was archived in the first place since there still seems to be a business need for it.

Comment: thanks for reply, we need archive this data because our database size is over than 1 TB, and we faced issues in rebuild index , back up db and so on, on other hand we don't edit this data anymore and need it just for some reports , have you any better idea?

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) Get a SQL expert to analyse the issues, maybe there is a solution so that the data can stay in the database. 2) Aggregate the data in a analysis services database and generate the reports (e.g. with PowerBI) from there.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/overview-of-the-microsoft-dynamics-ax-intelligent-data-management-framework-idmf#system-architecture) diagram, the archived data resides in a different database, which can be accessed from AX only using bespoke functionality e.g. using such system classes as `OdbcConnection`, `LoginProperty`, `SqlStatementExecutePermission`, `Statement`, etc. You could fetch this data into temporary tables and view them in AX grids, but that wouldn't work well for large sets of data.

[image]